# Where to find documentation for all query parameters in the googleapiclient library?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I saw the [following example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/customsearch/main.py), but short of going through the source code, I'm not sure of how to best understand the various ways to perform a search. For instance, what if I want to restrict the query to a particular domain?

```
import pprint

from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def main():
  # Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
  # the Google APIs Console <http://code.google.com/apis/console>
  # to get an API key for your own application.
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey="AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0")

  res = service.cse().list(
      q='lectures',
      cx='017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve',
    ).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Google publishes API reference documentation that includes parameter options for each of their APIs.

In your example, the "customsearch" [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list) for the "list" method shows all of the query parameters and their expected formats.

For your particular suggestion about restricting the query to a particular domain, the `siteSearch` and `siteSearchFilter` parameters will do the trick.

In general, if you don't have the API documentation on-hand, searching "Google API" + the API discovery name (i.e. "customsearch" in this case) will get you there. Then, from anywhere in the service's documentation, go to the top of the webpage and click the "References" section to find the REST API reference for that API.